# magento 2.4 add captcha to form in widget

Tags: magento2, forms, captcha

I've created a widget with a custom form. The form in the widget works fine but now I'd like to add the default magento captcha to this form and I don't know how to add it: all the articles I find are about adding it on the routeid_index_index.xml ma I don't have that. Having a widget, I only have the etc/widget.xml and a view/frontend/layout/default.xml in my module. I imagine I have to add it to the default.xml layout but I don't know how.